# Why the sum of factors is giving me wrong in r

Tags: r

```
speed<- c("15","20","30")
factor <- factor(speed, ordered= TRUE, levels = c("15","20","30"))
```

I'm trying to calculate mean, sum, min of the factor. How do I do it when I used `as.numeric()`? It's giving the sum as 6, min as 1.

Comment: Because it makes no sense to compute mean, sum, ecc. on factors. As you can read here for `mean` function, it needs a numeric vector and not a factor... https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/mean

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `as.numeric` is not doing what you are expecting.

```
as.numeric(factor)
[1] 1 2 3
```

The answers that you got are correct for these numbers.  But what I think you wanted was:

```
as.numeric(as.character(factor))
[1] 15 20 30
```